# JQuery Ajax success: function()

Tags: php, jquery

I post data to a php processing page like this:

```
$insert = mysql_query(
    'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' (' . substr($addfields,0,-1) . ') ' .
    'VALUES  (' . substr($addvals,0,-1) . ')');
```

I want to have:

```
if($insert): echo 'Message 1'; else: echo 'message2'; endif;
```

What do I do in my success: function() to display the message in `<div id="result"></div>` ?

I have tried:

```
success: function() {
     $(#result).html(html);
}
```

That code doesn't display the message in the div tag.

How do I post data to the div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) request is using `dataType: 'html'` (or the default, which will intelligently guess) your `success` function will receive the returned text as its first parameter:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/mypage.php',
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
  }
});
```

Should take whatever HTML your `mypage.php` dumps out, and replace the contents of the `<div id="result">` on the page just fine!

I have assembled a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nkVhu/) for you to look at.