# PHP Echo doesn't display in html

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I post data to `sa.php` via AJAX and on it I use  `$_POST['data']` to grab the post and echo it.  Now when I hit F12 to see the transfer it shows success. The $_POST['data'] shows up on the sa.php but when you look at the screen no text shows.

retrieve code:
                 
                            
           
Now here is my AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data: {"data": data},
           dataType: "text",
           success: function(data){
               console.log(data);
           },
           statusCode: {
               404: function() {
                   alert( "page not found" );
               }
           },
           complete: function (data) {
               console.info(data);
           }
       });
});
```

I'm trying to echo the `$_POST['data']` but it won't display in html.

Comment: You're logging to the console, not inserting to the HTML anywhere.

Comment: Can you show the PHP code for this request?

Comment: Offcourse it won't display. You are sending a ajax request on the background. Reload your oage using ajax or have a look in chrome developers tool. You can see what response your request gets

Comment: Ah I see..so how can I pull the data from the background?

Comment: What do you mean by _pull the data from the background_ Show a piece of your HTML around where you want this data to be placed on your page. Also show the PHP you are using to create the data that you echo back to the javascript

Comment: Remove }); in end of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As most comments point out you are not updating the HTML but rather just logging to the console....try this... create a div with an id "status"

In your page

```
<div id="status"></div>
```

and update your javascript

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data: {"data": data},
           dataType: "text",
           success: function(data){
               $('#status').html(data); //puts the response in a div with id status
               console.log(data);
           },
           statusCode: {
               404: function() {
                alert( "page not found" );
               }
           },
          complete: function (data) {
                 console.info(data);
          }
       });

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you would have a container div for where you want to echo your $_POST['data']? If you do, you can use that div as a selector using jQuery, where you can insert your AJAX data into it. To do that you add to your AJAX success function, something like the following:

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#containerDiv').html(data);
}
```

**Note: .html overwrites whatever is in your selector**

Have a look at the first answer of this question, i think this might help achieve what you need:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2972645/5525510

Comment: This is a comment and not really an answer

Comment: I made changes, would this be better?

Comment: So I cant ask someone for more information to help them answer their question, If I attempt to answer a question but cant, I dont get any reputation, and if I dont attempt to answer a question I cant get any reputation? how will I be able to ask someone for more information about their question, when i dont have enough reputation to ask someone for more information about their question?

Comment: In this case, the person who flagged the post made a mistake because the link is internal to stackoverflow network.